# Sum Numeric Values ​in String

Tags: java, string, sum

How can I add values ​​to a String? I want to create a shop inside my app using firebase database realtime, I created a button for the user to buy 100 coins, and I would like this value to be added, stored in firebase and then shown in TextView, the problem is that instead of adding , it remains the same value, in case when buying 100 it has to stay 100 in TextView, after buying 100 again it should be 200

```
comprarCem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BancoMoedas p = new BancoMoedas();
            int score = 120;
            p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            p.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());
            p.setNome(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(score)));     
            databaseReference.child("Usuarios").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);

        }
    });

private void eventoDataBase() {
    databaseReference.child("Usuarios").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            bancoMoedas.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                BancoMoedas p = objSnapshot.getValue(BancoMoedas.class);
                totalMoedas.setText(p.getNome()); //////////////// MOEDAS
                bancoMoedas.add(p);

            }
            arrayAdapterBancoMoeda = new ArrayAdapter<BancoMoedas>(Usuarios.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bancoMoedas);
            listV_dados.setAdapter(arrayAdapterBancoMoeda);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code for adding values? You can fetch existing value and covert that to Integer (a format that works for you) add recent value to it and put the updated value back to the database.

Comment: By pressing the button "buyCem" I would like it to sum the value, ie pressed once = 100
Next time 100 again, and 200 shows up in TextView "totalMoedas"

Comment: where is the code for on click Listner of buyCem button?

Comment: Dear friend, thank you in advance for your attention, I'm hours trying to fix this ..
Here is the code, I made some changes:

Comment: comprarCem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            int score = +120;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BancoMoedas p = new BancoMoedas();

                p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                p.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());
                p.setNome(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(score)));
                totalMoedas.setText(String.valueOf(score + score));

                databaseReference.child("Usuarios").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);

            }
        });